# Sort Properties in Artifactory Query Language

Tags: json, curl, artifactory, jfrog-cli, artifactory-query-lang

I'm trying to put together information for repositories in different stages. 
All my repos are appended with either Initial or Final at the end of the repository name. 
Eg: Repo = Maven-Build-Initial or Repo = Maven-Build-Final

I want to put together the following information using AQL - 
Name, Repository, Build name, Build number, Created, Type of repository (Java, .net etc)

I'm able to put together all the information other than the build name and build path for a particular arifact in a repository.

I saw the below example but couldn't understand -

```
items.find(

{

"@build.name":{"$match":"property value"},

"@build.number":{"$match":"property value"}

}

).include("name", "repo", "path", "created","@build.name","@build.number")
```

What exactly should be the "property value" in both build name and build number? If I have to fetch all the information for repository - Maven-Build-Initial, how would I run this query?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
items.find({
  "repo": {
    "$match": "<regex-to-match-your-repo-names>"
  }
}).include("name", "repo", "path", "created","@build.name","@build.number")
```

The include tells Artifactory  what to give you back in the results objects.

References:
https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Artifactory+Query+Language#ArtifactoryQueryLanguage-ComparisonOperators

https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Artifactory+REST+API#ArtifactoryRESTAPI-ArtifactoryQueryLanguage(AQL)

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the response. I managed resolving it using the same. Do you have any idea as to how could one also get information as to what type of repository is being used? Like if it is a docker repo or a maven one. What would be the query that would have to be added here?

Comment: It is not possible trough AQL at the time. But you can use the repository API.
GET /api/repositories/{repoKey} for each repo, or get all repositories GET /api/repositories[?type=repositoryType (local|remote|virtual|distribution)]

Comment: How can I further sort it to list only those repositories which haven’t been downloaded in the last 30 days? I know I need to use the stat.downloaded module but I keep getting syntax error.

Comment: Are you sure that AQL supports regular expressions? I don't see it mentioned anywhere in the docs and there are feature tickets currently open for it.

Comment: match supports wildcards and not regex. You can use '*' or '?'